# Error uploading SHP file to CartoDB

Tags: shapefile, carto

Trying my first map by uploading a SHP file.  The instructions tell me that I can upload a SHP file, but I get an error that they are not allowed.  This happens whether I upload by browsing a local directory, or by dragging a file into the CartoDB window.

Comment: you do realize a shapefile is not just one file? it is a collection of files with the same name (different extensions). The question is probably in line to be deleted because it is not really possible for someone to help with this information. What is the error? do you have some software to verify your shapefile is usable and correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the shapefile files into a zipped folder (.zip extension) and upload the files.

Add a folder, copy the desired shapefiles files (.shp, .shx, .sbn, .dbf, .prj) and paste them into the folder. Use a program like 7Zip to compress the folder to a .zip, as CartoDB does not like the .7z extension. You can then drag and drop the zipped folder into CartoDB.